# Error with a valor on For loop with a path with concatenation to read a xml file

Tags: python, for-loop

I've done a for loop with a valor who takes +1 at end of my loop.
My for loop is to read a xml file. It have to do an update when reading tag CP, on the file. I have 4 instructs with different tag. But my for loop stop to works after the first loop. 
Sorry for my bad english.

The incrementation works. I checked it with print.

```py
for cmd in root.iterfind('./instructs[@name="'+functions.str_instruct_number+'"]/command'):
    print('./instructs[@name="'+functions.str_instruct_number+'"]/command')
    print("cmd >",cmd.text)
    if cmd.text == "CP":
        try:
            for file in root.iterfind('./instructs[@name="'+functions.str_instruct_number+'"]/file'):
                print("file >", file.text)
                name_file = file.text
                tags_treatement_functions.CP_tag(name_file)
        except:
            print("for instruct morte")
        finally:
            print("finally CP pour voir")
            functions.instruct_number += 1
            functions.str_instruct_number = str(functions.instruct_number)
            print("INCREMENTATION", functions.instruct_number)
            print("INCREMENTATION STR", functions.str_instruct_number)
        tags_treatement_functions.RLD_tag(config.name_script)
    print(functions.instruct_number)
    print(functions.str_instruct_number)
    print(root.iterfind('./instructs[@name="'+functions.str_instruct_number+'"]/command'))
    print('./instructs[@name="'+functions.str_instruct_number+'"]/command')
    print("for finished")
print("for stopped")
```

that's my CP_tag function :

```py
def CP_tag(name_file):
    bool_copy = True
    for update_file in glob.glob(config.video_path+"*.*"):
        if name_file == update_file:
            print("pas de téléchargement")
            bool_copy = False
            break
    if bool_copy == True:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(config.FTP_adress, timeout=5)
        ftp.login(config.FTP_user, config.FTP_pwd)
        print("download ftp")
        try:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + name_file, open(config.local_temp_path+name_file, 'wb').write)
            print("download OK")
        except:
            print("download failed")
    bool_copy = True
```

Expect that my loop would done 4 loops, but it does only one
i dont know why because after one loop the valor is:
INCREMENTATION 2
INCREMENTATION STR 2

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The question is unclear. We cannot run your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `for cmd in "./instructs[@name="'+number_of_the_instruct+'"]/cmd"` that's my for who reads on my xml file. But after one loop, that doesn't works anymore, even if number_of_the_instruct+=1

Comment: I have 4 instructs in my xml file, and normally, my program would be read each of my instructs